# Keytool import certificate fails "Public keys in reply and keystore don't match"

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, keytool

I'm importing a SSL certificate to use in Tomcat in my keystore using keytool and it fails with *"Public keys in reply and keystore don't match"*

Problem might be declared by the fact that I created a new keystore after I accidentaly removed the old keystore file which I used from my CSR.

Now I received a .crt file and a .ca file. What's the best way to make SSL work under tomcat in my case now ?

Thanks in advance,

Bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your private key was in the keystore you accidently deleted. Public and private key must match, you cannot create one without the other.

(I'm cutting a few corners to keep it short)

The CSR has details about your public key. It is signed by an certificate authority (CA), and package it in a certificate. The private key is **not sent** to the CA.

So if you generated a new private-public key pair after deleting the original keystore, the public key you now have is not the one in the certificate you received. Even if there was a way to force the public key in there, the cryptography would not work.

You now have two choices :

- Restore a backup and get the old keystore back
- Make a new request

Comment: I requested a new certificate, tnx!